# Default state of C# record immutable attributes while deserializing if not serialized initially

Tags: c#, .net, struct, deserialization, record

I have a record struct construct in C# that will be updated to contain two new attributes like below:

Existing Record:

```
public record struct RecordA(ABC data);
```

Updated record:

```
public record struct RecordA(ABC data, DateTime dateTime, int count);
```

These records would be serialized and saved into a document database, and would later be deserialized and read.

There exists a possibility where initially the producer might not be saving the serialized record with the additional attributes, but while fetching it might read the additional attributes and take appropriate action based on the values.
What would be the default state of these attributes when fetching them while deserialization?

I am new to C# hence would like to know, what would be a good way to handle this situation given that this has to be rolled out without any code break.

Comment: That may depend on the actual serializer used you didn't specify. But without seeing details here having used records (so relying on automatic stuff created by that choice) and then running into problems maintaining the code because you lost control over what is happening to a certain degree seems expected to me.

Comment: A `record struct` is mainly useful for value-type DTOs. It is extremely strange to “update” or “extend” one. Attempting this would probably create duplicate slow, inefficient records with all the problems of mutable structs. Explain why you think you need to use them. I suggest using `record class`, making them immutable, and using inheritance for “additional attributes”.